# Download button in vercel getting 404 file

Tags: next.js, download, http-status-code-404, vercel

[This shows what happens when I click the button. It opens the window as if it was going to save a file but it only shows me a 404 "file" and does not save anything.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsoYD.png)

The problem is that when I click on a button to download a pdf file in my portfolio I get 404. The portfolio is in vercel and was created with nextjs 14.

This is the element

```
<div className="flex">
              <a
                href="./public/Dereck_Resume.pdf"
                download={"Dereck-Resume.pdf"}
                className="border-2 mr-10 rounded-lg text-xl  py-2 px-5 transition-colors duration-300 blinking"
              >
                Resume
              </a>
            </div>
```

When I run my code on my pc it works but on vercel it does not.

Comment: HI Dereck. It would be possible that the file you are looking for is not in the given location